# How to add node_modules folder in a global npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I have created an npm package which has a lot of dependencies, but when I test my app with `npm install -g ./` the app gets added in the global npm directory but without the node-modules folder. Thus when the app is run through the terminal, although the app is recognized, it doesn't work because none of the dependency is installed.

How can I make sure to make app installs node-modules when its published in the npm registry

If I install the node-modules independently on the project folder by doing `npm install`, the app works. I don't want the user to install the packages independently. What I am expecting is the full installation of the app and the required dependencies only with `npm install -g my_package`

I have also used yarn as the package manager, and the dependencies are listed under "dependencies" in package.json file. The "bin" field in the package.json file points to our app, which can also be run as `node bin/index.js`. This app is also recognized by the terminal, the only problem is the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this command `npm install --save` then it might work.